# Original list is altered when I iterate over and alter a copy of it

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My questions is regarding lists in Python 3. In the code below, I give a method from a class whose purpose is to imitate the mathematical behavior of polynomials. The class will consist of methods for polynomial arithmetic, as well as one attribute. This attribute is a list of the coefficients in the polynomial, with the elements listed in the normal order for polynomials. For example, 7x^3+3x+4 becomes [7,0,3,4]

The add() method below is an attempt to imitate what is visually a right-justified addition, as in normal arithmetic. It does so by finding first which list is shorter, then adding its elements to the corresponding elements in the longer list, and then returning the longer list with this alteration. However, I don't want the side-effect of actually altering either of the original lists, and so I've assigned the original lists to the method-internal lists greater and lesser. When I create two polynomials p = P([1,2,3]) and q = P([1,2,3]), and then call p.add(q), the addition happens, but nothing is printed to the screen, and when I check p.coeffs, it shows as [2,4,6].

```
class P:
    coeffs = []

    def __init__(self,coeffs):
        self.coeffs = coeffs


    def add(self,q):
        if len(self.coeffs) >= len(q.coeffs):
            greater = self.coeffs
            lesser = q.coeffs

        else:
            greater = q.coeffs
            lesser = self.coeffs
        i = -1
        while i >= -len(lesser):
            greater[i] = greater[i]+lesser[i]
            i=i-1

        return greater
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 4):

`greater = self.coeffs` doesn't make a copy of `self.coeffs`. `greater` and `self.coeffs` now point to the same list object.

If you want to clone a list, either slice it:

```
greater = self.coeffs[:]
```

Or pass it through the `list` builtin:

```
greater = list(self.coeffs)
```

Also, you should override `__add__` instead of making your own method, as that'll let you actually add the two objects with the addition operator.

You may also find it easier to add the polynomials together if you represent them "backwards" (e.g. `2x^2 + 1` becomes `[1, 0, 2]`)